# Syntax error on bash script with fi

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to make a cron to send me a mail when my disk runs out of space in the server.
I managed to get something working but it keeps giving me stupid errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISKUSAGE=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
ALERT=90
EMAILTO="admin@example.com"
EMAILSUBJECT="Server "
EMAILMESSAGE=" Your partition is running out of space. Used $DISKUSAGE"
if [$DISKUSAGE -gt $ALERT]
then
    echo $EMAILMESSAGE
fi
```

And I am receiving the following error

```
root@ds5890:~# bash checkspace.sh
checkspace.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
checkspace.sh: line 10: `fi'
```

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong.
This seems to be to strict. One space missing and nothing works.

I am also trying to put the character % in the string but it doesn't work. I tried with \% /% with no luck.

Comment: Use a space after ```[``` and before ```]``` (```[``` acutally is a programm which is called). For bash internal evaluation use ```[[``` and ```]```.

Comment: I tried to run the command ls using `lsfoo`.  It seems pretty strict that a space missing causes the shell to try to run a command named `lsfoo` instead of `ls` with an argument of `foo`.  `[` is not shell syntax.  `[` is a command.

Comment: None of the solutions worked.
Even if I copy these examples nothing works.
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: Your script works perfectly fine for me if I'm adding the spaces as proposed by @MrTux

Comment: Please, check the value of the DISKUSAGE variable is number. Use spaces surrounding the [ and ] and use double quotes in the if. Check the hyphen character is the real ASCII hyphen and there is no weird character (use od -tx1 -tc checkspace.sh to check every single character)

Comment: Running your program through http://shellcheck.net/ would have made asking here completely unnecessary.

Comment: @bucur89, if "nothing works", I'm guessing that your scripts have DOS-formatted newlines rather than being proper UNIX text files. This puts an extra `$'\r'` character on the end of each line, which will have the effect you describe -- of absolutely nothing working. Running your script with `bash -x yourscript` will make this problem clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use a space after `[` and before `]` (`[` actually is a program which is called by bash).

I.e. when using `[` the external program is called for every evaluation; you can avoid that by using `[[` and `]]` for bash internal evaluation.

You should also consider quoting (using double quotes) the variables used in the if-statement.

Comment: While there is an external program `/bin/[`, Bash also has a built-in `[` command which is used unless you write `/bin/[` or `/bin/test`.  However, you're entirely correct that you must treat `[` as a command name that must, therefore, be separate from its arguments, and when it is invoked as `[` (or `/bin/[`) rather than as `test` or `/bin/test`, the last argument must be `]` which must also, therefore, be separate from the other arguments.  The `[[` command is also built-in.

Comment: After a while of trying to get it working I stoped, it might be the configuration on my server, but nothing worked... :(